get-method of an array list gives "object" and not specific class back
I try to manage an Array list of AccessCodes, which are a simple class. In the class Robot I want to get access of one element of the ArrayList and use the method getUsed(), which is defined in the class AccessCode. But i get an error
./Robot.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
if (codeList.get(i).getUsed()) {
                               ^
  symbol:   method getUsed()
  location: class Object

it seems that i get not an AccessCode-Object back but an Object-Object. But if i try to just print the element it seems that i get the AccessCode-Objects.
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Story {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<AccessCode> accessCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        AccessCode code1 = new AccessCode("Federvieh", true);
        AccessCode code2 = new AccessCode("e.vil", true);
        AccessCode code3 = new AccessCode("Haifischbecken", false);
        AccessCode code4 = new AccessCode("2A2A", false);
        accessCodes.add(code1);
        accessCodes.add(code2);
        accessCodes.add(code3);
        accessCodes.add(code4);
        
        Robot ronja = new Robot();
        ronja.saveCodes(accessCodes);
        ronja.buildHashMap();
    }
}
class AccessCode {

    private String code;
    private boolean used;

    AccessCode(String code, boolean used) {
        this.code = code;
        this.used = used;           
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public boolean getUsed() {
        return used;
    }
}
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Robot {

    ArrayList<AccessCode> usedAccessCodes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<AccessCode> unusedAccessCodes = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList> codeHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void saveCodes(ArrayList codeList){
        AccessCode temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < codeList.size(); i ++){
            System.out.println(codeList.get(i)+"\n");
            
            if (codeList.get(i).getUsed()) {
                usedAccessCodes.add(codeList.get(i));
            } else{
                unusedAccessCodes.add(codeList.get(i));
            }
            
        }
    }
     public void buildHashMap(){
         codeHashMap.put("used", usedAccessCodes);
         codeHashMap.put("unused", unusedAccessCodes);
     }
}


I expect, that
codeList.get(i).getUsed()

gives the used-attribute from the Access-Code-Object in the ArrayList codeList.

The declaration of method saveCodes should be: public void saveCodes(ArrayList<AccessCode> codeList)

thank you very much. This solved the problem!
